# Entering the Schengen area 12 days before my visa expires

Tags: visas, schengen, legal, study, vietnamese-citizens

I have a Vietnamese passport. I'm planning to visit Vietnam on July 7th and be back in the Czech Republic (in Schengen area) on August 29th. My visa is a multiple-entry, long-term, D type visa (for study purposes) and the expiration date is September 10th. I am afraid that the boarding officer will not allow me to enter EU since the arrival is so close to the expiration date.

Is it OK for me to enter Schengen on August 29th when I have only 12 days left until visa expiration?

Comment: What kind of visa is it?  Also, August 29 through September 10, inclusive, is 13 days.  Where do you get 9?

Comment: Long-term visa for students- D type. Oh, maybe I've made mistakes. Wrong calculating -sorry, however, I think just a few days left in my visa will make my entry to Schengen area more difficult.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that you'll have trouble here. If you had a standard short term 'visitor' visa maybe. But your visa is for studies. If you need to return for the last few days/weeks to finish your assignments, etc, I would think there should be no problem.

Comment: Will you be able to demonstrate (perhaps by showing tickets) that you plan to leave on or before September 10th?

Comment: I plan to submit the missing documents to complete the visa extension process when I come back. But these days, it's getting difficult for Vietnamese to enter Schengen area with a few days left on visa since some Vietnamese do take advantage of it : overstay and participate in illegal activities :( I just wonder if the boarding office have the right to be suspicious and prevent me to enter EU.

Comment: You say it is a D visa? How many entries? single? multiple? D visas are given for residence permits usually more than 6 months validity. do you have a pink card? In most EU countries, D visas had to be renewed before 30 days in advance. In your case, you have to apply for extension by staying in Czech republic (before 30 days) by Aug 9 deadline . IF not once you leave the country, you can only apply at the embassy in Vietnam for renewal. Please check what i have said is true! I suggest you first apply for extension (earlier before 30 days is good) and then leave the country.

Comment: multiple entries. I have a pink card called biometric card, they said that i could use it instead of visa. I've already came to the alien police for visa extension but I lack two types of documents and I intend to submit the missing documents when I flied back which means my visa extension is being postponed till the day I submit all required documents.

Comment: Have you eventually entered the Schengen area with your documents? I believe there would be a few of us who would appreciate if you shared your experiences.

Answer (score 7):

Your visa is valid until 23:59:59 on the expiration date. Therefore, from a strictly bureaucratic point of view, you should be allowed to re-enter the Schengen area since you have a valid visa. However, as you say, the immigration officer might have some questions regarding the closeness of the expiry date to your date of entry in the country.

If you want to shed some light on those doubts bring all supporting documents that you think are necessary to explain your situation. These can be in the form of a proof of onward travel - i.e. plane tickets out of the Schengen area on a date prior to the expiry of your visa - or of a proof that you have applied for a visa extension and are likely to get it - say the application submission receipt along with a proof of student status lasting longer than your current visa validity window.

All in all you are the one responsible for bringing the right documentation to support your case. Also I suggest you be honest with the immigration officer and don't try any tricks.